# How Can I Log A User Into YouTube Through My iPod Touch Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

I have come across a slight problem in my programming of an iPod Touch application. However I am very enthusiastic that it can be solved and that a nudge in the right direction will be of great help. I have experience with Objective C, XCode and the essential app builders included with XCode also.

My question is, as the title says, how do I log a user into YouTube through my iPod Touch application? I have looked through the countless API documentation for YouTube, objective c and many other google APIs. After all my searching for the last few days I have found that OAuth2 seems to be the most lightweight way to connect a user to YouTube in an application. All it requires is the client id and client secret.

However, even knowing this, I am finding it difficult to understand the code needed to simply connect a user to YouTube through my application. Could anyone perhaps suggest a sample code? Or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

Code samples are here:
http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/wiki/GTMOAuthIntroduction#Signing_In_to_Google_Services

Additional info are here: http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/ and here: http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/

Hope it will help you.

Comment: GMT is Google Toolbox for Mac.

Comment: Thankyou for your help Greg, however I have already read through the documents provided by these links. I have learned a lot about OAuth but not exactly a way to use it, as in useable code. Would anyone be so good as to provide the code that could be used to log a user into youtube through and iPhone app? The specific token values could be left out. I would be very grateful.. :)